# Opinion: web app or PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, iphone-standalone-web-app

Saavy is game for front-end designers and developers.

I'm getting ready to enter my beta testing phase. I wanted to get the community's opinion on launching as a web-app vs wrapping it in Cordova/PhoneGap.

Go ahead, try it out and let me know if you think wrapping it in PhoneGap/Cordova could improve the overall experience.

http://saavy.herokuapp.com

Thanks!!

---

bonus video to help stimulate some ideas:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fchbLzwtexk

Answer (score 0):

wrapping Saavy in Phonegap will make it faster and will let you got new features,
It may let you send pushNotifications, see statistics, protect your code, etc...

Ps:
To submit it in Play store you should get an account for 25$.
To submit it in Apple store you should get an account for 99$ + you should submit it from a mac pc/laptop.